# Python not showing correct version on Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew, python-3.7

I am trying to update Python to 3.7.4 on my Mac. Currently when I type python3 --version, it shows that I have Python 3.7.3 I have tried to update using just the standalone installer from the website as well as homebrew but even through all of these methods, python3 --version still returns to me 3.7.3. Even when I try to upgrade with Brew, it says that 3.7.4 is installed...

Picture for reference:

[image]

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `type python` show?

Comment: I'm a Linux user,  but check out what "python" actually points to. It's often a symlink that gets rearranged on installs. Because reasons, I have three different pythons installed ATM.

Comment: @kt-worflow, I hope my answers helps you, I have experienced some issues installing Python previously, and what I posted in my answered worked for me. Let me know if you have further problems.

Comment: Try `which -a python` to see *all* the Pythons available on your path. `python --version` just runs the *first* one that is found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Check what python version you are using by running `which python`, at this point you might figure out what version of Python is being used to solve this problem. Otherwise, follow up this steps:

I would remove all Python installations and use Homebrew to install it.

First, run `which python`:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Delete the entire Python.framework directory from /Library/Frameworks.

Second, run `which python3`:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Again, delete the entire python3 directory.

Now use `brew doctor` in order to see possible issues with symlinks. If you have issues run `brew prune` or `brew cleanup --prune`. This will remove all of the symlinks.

Reinstall python and python3 via homebrew:

```
brew install python
```

Comment: I can't remove anything from those directories, as it says it's required by Mac OS.

Comment: @kt-workflow, what if you run `sudo rm /Library/Frameworks/`

Comment: Hi miguel, your comment helped. When I ran 'which python', I was able to find out that it was stored in miniconda3, which was running 3.7.3. All I had to do was delete that path. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @kt-workflow, you're welcome. I glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Some older apps may count on the Python2.7 framework being installed. It sounds like you may not have your bash $PATH set to look for homebrew binaries before the built-in ones.  You can edit your `~/.profile` file, and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is the first entry by adding the following line to the end of `.profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python

https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30220726)

Answer (score 0):

Just type in the below and it'll work

python3 --version

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question in any way. The question is not about how to show your current python-version, but how to upgrade it to another one.